# "'Module is opened" or "Module is open"?

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Which sentence is correct: 'Module is opened" or "Module is open"? I use this phrase a lot at work and would like to be correct.

Comment: Are you using the phrase as a full sentence?

Comment: Is Module a name or do you mean **a module**, as in "The module is open"?

Comment: @TheRealLester it is a full sentence

Comment: @Mattias a module, as in "The module is open"?

Answer (score 3):

**Open** (= not closed) is an *adjective*, **(is) opened** is a *verb* in passive.

> This module is opened (by qualified personnel) using a screwdriver.

(how to perform the action of opening it)

> In this picture the module is open.

(it is in its 'open' state, like 'the doors are open')

> The module is open by design.

(it has no protective case)